# EasyaAmin 3 - Hide/Show actions dynamically based on the underlying entity

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

Is there any way to show/hide actions based on the underlying entity? For example, I need to show the delete action of a Category entity if and only if it doesn't have any children post.

I tried to remove that from `configureActions` method in my CRUD controller, but I haven't access to the `AdminContext` object when that method is being called.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

After tracing in EasyAdmin's code base I found this solution:

Consider I have a `Category` entity with a `OneToMany` relation to posts. I need to show `delete` action of each category if the category doesn't have any post.

```php
    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        $action = parent::configureActions($actions)->getAsDto(Crud::PAGE_INDEX)->getAction(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DELETE);

        if (!\is_null($action)) {
            $action->setDisplayCallable(function (Category $category) {
                return $category->getPosts()->count() === 0;
            });   
        }

        return $actions;
    }
```